# Cannot build Sencha Touch 2.1 app with Sencha Cmd 3.1.1.274

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd, sencha-command

I am trying to package a sencha touch 2.1 app (generated with `Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.250`) with the newest version of Sencha Cmd (3.1.1.274). When I run `sencha app build package` in the root of the project, I get this error:

`[ERR] The app was last modified by a newer version of Sencha Cmd (+?), current is 3.1.1.274.  Please update Sencha Cmd.

 [ERR] Application Cmd version mismatch.`

I don't think you can get an older version of Sencha Cmd so does anyone know how I should go about getting my project to build using the latest version of Sencha Cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this could help but incase if you are looking to download a lower version of Sencha Cmd. The below link has it:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248208-Sencha-Cmd-V3.0-GA-%283.0.0.250%29-Now-Available

If you just scroll down, you can see a bunch of links that gives you Sencha Cmd 3.0.0.250 for different OS.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why my answer was deleted by a moderator. Obviously he is not a Sencha developer.

Was the Sencha app originally generated on Windows? It looks like your system doesn't know which sencha cmd version was used, hence the (?). I encountered the same issue once I switched to Mac.

You can verify if you indeed have an older version of CMD by viewing the file PROJECT_ROOT/touch/cmd/sencha.cfg

Comment: Yes the app was generated on a windows machine and after looking at the `sencha.cfg` file it says version `3.0.0.250`